# android facebook post api not working

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am using android facebook api for publishing on users feed.

Login is working successfully,
but the function publishstory is not working. I have the code below.

```
private void publishStory() {

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

        if (session != null){

            // Check for publish permissions    
            List<String> permissions = session.getPermissions();
            if (!isSubsetOf(PERMISSIONS, permissions)) {
                pendingPublishReauthorization = true;
                Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session
                        .NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSIONS);
            session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }

            Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
            postParams.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
            postParams.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
            postParams.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
            postParams.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
            postParams.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

            Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response
                                               .getGraphObject()
                                               .getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("error",
                            "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
                    }
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    if (error != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this.getApplicationContext(),
                             error.getErrorMessage(),
                             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(FacebookActivity.this
                                 .getApplicationContext(), 
                                 postId,
                                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            };

            Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, 
                                  HttpMethod.POST, callback);

            RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
            task.execute();
        }

    }
```

the problem is it executes till line

```
session.requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
                return;
            }
```

and then comes out of the function on return without showing any popup. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return must be called only for fragment activity I was doing it in a normal activity which created the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this code ->

[FbShare Code Pattern Gist](https://gist.github.com/vishalpawale/5556996)

Answer (score 0):

As you showed the code call the `requestNewPublishPermissions()` when the access token is found without the necessary permissions.
But in order to complete the action after the request you have to define the `Session.StatusCallback`.

```
private static Session.StatusCallback sessionCallback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        Log.i(TAG, "callback");
        if (exception == null) {
            if (pendingPublishAction && state.isOpened()) {
                pendingPublishAction = false;
                //do your post action;
            }
        }
        else{
            //handle exception
        }
    }
};
```

However, from what you said, it seemed that not even the dialog for the new permissions is showed. Did you implement the `onActivityResult`like this?

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if (session != null) {
        session.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

If you did so there must have been some other kind of error during the authentication phase, in this case logcat should show something.